# Need to plot a cosine function in hours when it's calculated in seconds

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot the following function with matplotlib but have run into a problem I haven't dealt with before.

Function: `F0*cos((pi*(t-12))/12)` where `t` is from 0 to 86400 seconds.

I need that function to be calculated for every second not just for accuracy but because the function this cos represents is measured in Watts/m^2.

I'm trying to plot this function but only want the x-axis to be from 0 to 24 hours instead of 0 to 86400 seconds so the plot does not turn out like this:

[image]

Here's my code and thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)
F0 = 500.0

t = np.arange(0, 86400, 1)
s = F0*(np.cos((np.pi*(t-12))/12))
line, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Why not devide by 3600 `plt.plot(t/3600, s, lw=1)`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: that wont' work. You have to convert before computing `s`

Comment: What have you done to attempt a unit conversion from seconds to hours?

Comment: @Bazingaa The question says that `t` in the equation is time in seconds but the accepted  answer says it is time in hours.

Comment: @Goyo: From the OP's comment under my question and from looking at the equation having the factor `12`, it seemed clear that the OP wanted and should have used time in hours in the equation. In my opinion, that was no reason to downvote, whoever did so. Although the OP wrote that "I need that function to be calculated for every second ", this was not he/she intended. So it became apparent to him/her that he.she should have used time in hours in the equation. But anyway, the downvoter is long gone perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the time from seconds to hours by dividing `t` by 3600 **before** computing `s` because you are using the factor 12 in your equation which refers to hours. If you convert them after computing `s`, you will not get the desired plot. So you should use

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)
F0 = 500.0

t = np.arange(0, 86400, 1)/3600
s = F0*(np.cos((np.pi*(t-12))/12))
line, = plt.plot(t, s)
```

[image]

**P.S** Don't do the following because here you compute `s` using time in seconds but then plot time in hours which will give incorrect scaling on the x-axis

```
t = np.arange(0, 86400, 1)
s = F0*(np.cos((np.pi*(t-12))/12))
line, = plt.plot(t/3600, s)
```

Comment: Thanks, just accepted the answer. Was trying to earlier but it said I had to wait for a couple more minutes

Comment: @JoelPorcaro: Glad to help. You are welcome. I still don't know why and who downvoted my perfectly fine answer